# How to print Depth to a Texture2D and then read it in the next pass on a shader in DirectX11

Tags: textures, directx, directx11, depth-buffer, sharpdx

I'm programming a two-pass effect in DirectX 11 (SharpDX). It's supposed to write the depth to a texture in the first pass and then use that texture to extract data on the second one in the pixel shader.

What I get is a white screen, with nothing but the interface and I don't know why nothing is being printed. What could be the problem? I would say I should get at least something from the Depth Texture.

This is how I'm setting the depth texture values:

```
this.depthBuffer = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription()
        {
            Format = Format.R32_Typeless,
            ArraySize = 1,
            MipLevels = 1,
            Width = (int)host.ActualWidth,
            Height = (int)host.ActualHeight,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
            BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil | BindFlags.ShaderResource,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
            OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
        });

this.depthBufferShaderResourceView = new ShaderResourceView(this.device, this.depthBuffer, new ShaderResourceViewDescription()
        {
            Format = Format.R32_Float,
            Dimension = ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture2D,
            Texture2D = new ShaderResourceViewDescription.Texture2DResource()
            {
                MipLevels = 1,
                MostDetailedMip = 0,
            }
        });
var depthStencilDesc = new DepthStencilStateDescription()
        {
            DepthComparison = Comparison.LessEqual,
            DepthWriteMask = global::SharpDX.Direct3D11.DepthWriteMask.All,
            IsDepthEnabled = true,
        };
```

And here is how I sample the depth in the .fx file:

```
int3 posTex = int3(input.p.xy, 0);
float depthPixel = DepthTexture.Load(posTex);
float4 color = float4(depthPixel, depthPixel , depthPixel, 1.0f );
return color;
```

And here the way I'm now setting the Depth Buffer stencil view as a Render Target in 2 passes. In the first I try to set the depthstencilview as a target. In the second pass I'm trying to set teh depth texture as a shader resource to read from it.

```
this.device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(this.vertexBuffer, LinesVertex.SizeInBytes, 0));

// PASS 0
this.device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthBufferStencilView);
this.device.ImmediateContext.ClearDepthStencilView(this.depthBufferStencilView,     DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth | DepthStencilClearFlags.Stencil, 1.0f, 0);
this.technique.GetPassByIndex(0).Apply(this.device.ImmediateContext);
this.device.ImmediateContext.DrawIndexed(this.geometry.Indices.Length, 0, 0);

// PASS 1
this.device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.ResetTargets(); // unbinding the depthStencilView

this.device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(this.vertexBuffer, LinesVertex.SizeInBytes, 0));
this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable = effect.GetVariableByName("DepthTexture").AsShaderResource();
this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable.SetResource(this.depthBufferShaderResourceView);
this.technique.GetPassByIndex(1).Apply(this.device.ImmediateContext);
this.device.ImmediateContext.DrawIndexed(this.geometry.Indices.Length, 0, 0);
```

Finally, this is how I set the two passes in the .fx file:

```
technique11 RenderMyTechnique
{
pass P0
{   

SetDepthStencilState( DSSDepthLessEqual, 0 );
SetVertexShader     ( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VShader() ) );
    SetHullShader       ( NULL );
    SetDomainShader     ( NULL );        
    SetGeometryShader   ( NULL  );
SetPixelShader      ( NULL );
}

pass P1
{
SetDepthStencilState( DSSDepthLessEqual, 0 );
SetVertexShader     ( CompileShader( vs_4_0, VShader() ) );
    SetHullShader       ( NULL );
    SetDomainShader     ( NULL );        
    SetGeometryShader   ( CompileShader( gs_4_0, GShader() ) );
SetPixelShader      ( CompileShader( ps_4_0, PShader() ) );
}
}
```

Comment: Obvious question: Are you actually writing to the depth buffer for sure?

Comment: how can I be sure? I thought it was just always done.

Comment: @c4sh You also have to create a [`DepthStencilView`](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-direct3d11-depthstencilview) of the buffer (using the `D32_FLOAT` format) and pass it in your `SetRenderTargets` call.

Comment: @c4sh: You also have to make sure that `DepthWrite` is turned on in your `DepthStencilState` bound to the context when rendering when you render your scene.  I don't recall if it's set by default, but it might not be.

Comment: Following the comments I passed the `DepthStencilView` to my `SetRenderTargets` call and set a `DepthStencilState` with `IsDepthEnabled` as `true` (added the DepthStencilStateDescription in the question.

(see changes in question)

So I realized I'm now getting always a 1.0f because I'm clearing the DepthBuffer to 1.0f. So I'm not writing on it, the thing is I don't know why I'm not writing to it..? @NathanReed @SeanMiddleditch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you've bound the texture for reading and writing at the same time (i.e. it's the current depth buffer). DX11 won't let you do that (the debug runtime should give you an error message about it).

Also note that it decides what the current depth buffer is at the time you bind the shader resource, and not at draw call time so you want to bind the correct set of render targets before binding any shader resources.

There are three solutions:

1. Unbind the depth buffer while reading from it in a shader. This assumes you don't need depth testing.
2. Copy the depth buffer at some point, and read from the copy. This is clearly the slowest option.
3. Bind the depth buffer as read only. This won't work on 10.0 or 10.1 hardware.

Comment: I would take the third approach as I need it to be fast and I really need the depth buffer.

The problem is, I don't know how to bind the depth buffer as read only. I'm binding it like this:

`this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable = effect.GetVariableByName("DepthTexture").AsShaderResource();

           this.depthStencilShaderResourceVariable.SetResource(this.depthBufferShaderResourceView);`

I don't know if you mean this types of resource usage: http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-direct3d11-resourceusage

But didn't see anything useful in them.

Comment: You need to pass D3D11_DSV_READ_ONLY_DEPTH to CreateDepthStencilView() to get a read-only view. For SharpDX I think that's done by calling http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d11-depthstencilview--ctor-1 and setting the Description up appropriately.

Comment: This leaves it just with 0s. So the depth buffer was cleared to 1.0 but it's as if I was writing zeroes on it!

Comment: As no one else is gonna answer this and the problem for me is not solved, I would accept the answer I got as a thanks giving for its usefulness, though it didn't lead me to a solution.