# Apply multiple Shaders to one texture with DirectX

Tags: shaders, textures, directx

I'm beginning with DirectX development and I'm quite confused by the documentation about how to do the following:

**I have 1 image (Texture2D), I'd like to apply 2 independent HLSL, one after the other, and render it.**

For instance, one shader makes the texture semi-transparent, the other turns it to black and white.
Also, I'm computing everything off-screen, so I don't have a SwapChain.

So far the output texture I get has the 1st shader applied but not the second. If I switch the order where the shaders are applied, then I'm seeing the 1st shader applied (in the new order) but not the second. In other words, both shaders work separately but not together.
I'm using SharpDX and C#.

### Here is what I made

#### Setup

1. Create D3D11 device.
2. Set Blend state

```
            BlendStateDescription blendStateDescription = new BlendStateDescription
            {
                AlphaToCoverageEnable = false,
                IndependentBlendEnable = false
            };
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].IsBlendEnabled = true;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SourceBlend = BlendOption.SourceAlpha;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestinationBlend = BlendOption.InverseSourceAlpha;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SourceAlphaBlend = BlendOption.One;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestinationAlphaBlend = BlendOption.One;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].AlphaBlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = ColorWriteMaskFlags.All;

            device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetBlendState(new BlendState(device, blendStateDescription));
```

3. Set Depth stencil state

```
            var depthStencilState = new DepthStencilState(device, DepthStencilStateDescription.Default());
            device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(depthStencilState);
```

4. Create a RenderTargetView and a texture
5. Create DepthStencilView and a texture
6. Set the RenderTargetView and DepthStencilView are targets of the output merger.

#### Run

1. Load an image from the hard drive to a Texture2D
2. Create a ShaderResourceView from this texture.
3. For each effects I want to apply:

   - Load the shader from the bytecode into an Effect.
   - Create a vertice, then create a buffer from it.
   - Set this buffer as a vertex buffer in the Input Assembler: `deviceContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(myBuffer, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(VertexPositionTexture)), 0));`
   - Set the input layout.
   - Get a `technique` from the shader and for each pass, I `effectPass.Apply` then do a `deviceContext.Draw`.
4. `deviceContext.Flush();`
5. Save the texture associated to the RenderTargetView as a PNG.

### Question

Is my approach correct or am I doing something wrong in that method?

I wonder if the issue could be in the blend state or depth stencil.
Let me know if you'd like me to share more code to see my implementation details.

Thank you in advance for the help. :)

## [UPDATE 3/8/21]

Here is a simplified version of my code for insights:

```
var device = new Device(
                    DriverType.Hardware,
                    DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport | DeviceCreationFlags.VideoSupport,
                    FeatureLevel.Level_11_0);

            BlendStateDescription blendStateDescription = new BlendStateDescription
            {
                AlphaToCoverageEnable = false,
            };
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].IsBlendEnabled = true;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SourceBlend = BlendOption.SourceAlpha;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestinationBlend = BlendOption.InverseSourceAlpha;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].SourceAlphaBlend = BlendOption.Zero;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].DestinationAlphaBlend = BlendOption.Zero;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].AlphaBlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add;
            blendStateDescription.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = ColorWriteMaskFlags.All;

            device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetBlendState(new BlendState(device, blendStateDescription));


            DepthStencilStateDescription description = DepthStencilStateDescription.Default();
            description.DepthComparison = Comparison.LessEqual;
            description.IsDepthEnabled = true;

            device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(new DepthStencilState(device, description));

// [...]

            Texture2DDescription depthDesc = new Texture2DDescription()
            {
                Width = _outputTextureSize.Width,
                Height = _outputTextureSize.Height,
                Format = Format.D24_UNorm_S8_UInt,
                OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                ArraySize = 1,
                MipLevels = 1,
                SampleDescription =
                {
                    Count = 1,
                    Quality = 0
                },
                BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                Usage = ResourceUsage.Default
            };

            DepthStencilViewDescription depthViewDesc = new DepthStencilViewDescription()
            {
                Dimension = DepthStencilViewDimension.Texture2D,
                Format = Format.D24_UNorm_S8_UInt,
            };

            _depthStencilTexture = new Texture2D(device, depthDesc);
            _depthStencilView = new DepthStencilView(device, _depthStencilTexture, depthViewDesc);
            device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(
                new DepthStencilState(device,
                DepthStencilStateDescription.Default()));


// RENDERING

            context.ClearRenderTargetView(_renderTargetView, Color.CornflowerBlue);
            context.ClearDepthStencilView(_depthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1f, 0);

            using ShaderResourceView shaderResourceView = new ShaderResourceView(device, inputTexture2D)

foreach (var effect in effectList)
{
    using ShaderBytecode shaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.FromFile(effect.FilePath);
    var shaderEffect = new Effect(device, shaderByteCode.Data);

    using var verticesRectangle = new DataStream(
                Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(VertexPositionTexture)) * 4,
                true,
                true);

    // verticesRectangle.Write ...
    verticesRectangle.Position = 0;
    var buffer
                = new Buffer(
                    device,
                    verticesRectangle,
                    new BufferDescription
                    {
                        BindFlags = BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
                        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                        OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                        SizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(VertexPositionTexture)) * 4,
                        Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                        StructureByteStride = 0
                    });

    device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.InputLayout
                    = new InputLayout(
                        device,
                        shaderEffect.GetTechniqueByIndex(0).GetPassByIndex(0).Description.Signature,
                        elements: VertexPositionTexture.InputElements);

     device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleStrip;
     device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(
                    0,
                    new VertexBufferBinding(
                        buffer,
                        Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(VertexPositionTexture)),
                        0));

    for (var i = 0; i < shaderEffect.GetTechniqueByIndex(0).Description.PassCount; ++i)
    {
                    using EffectPass effectPass = shaderEffect.GetTechniqueByIndex(0).GetPassByIndex(i);

                    if (effectPass.IsValid)
                    {
                        effectPass.Apply(deviceContext);
                    }

                    device.ImmediateContext.Draw(4, 0);
                }

                device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.InputLayout.Dispose();
                device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.InputLayout = null;
}

device.ImmediateContext.Flush();
```

My shader effects:

```
///
/// Shader effect that changes the opacity of a texture.
///

Texture2D Texture : register(t0);
SamplerState TextureSampler : register(s0);

float TargetOpacity;

struct ShaderParameters
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position; // vertex position input
    float2 TextureUV : TEXCOORD0; // first texture coordinate input
};

// Vertex Shader
ShaderParameters VS(ShaderParameters input)
{
    ShaderParameters output = (ShaderParameters) 0;

    output.Position = input.Position;
    output.TextureUV = input.TextureUV;

    return output; // Returns the position without any change to it.
}

// Pixel Shader
float4 PS(ShaderParameters input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 rgbaColor = Texture.Sample(TextureSampler, input.TextureUV);

    return float4(rgbaColor.rgb, rgbaColor.a * TargetOpacity);
}

technique10 OpacityTechnique
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetGeometryShader(0);
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, VS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, PS()));
    }
}
```

And

```
///
/// Shader effect that converts a colorful texture to monochrome (gray).
///

Texture2D Texture : register(t0);
SamplerState TextureSampler : register(s0);

struct ShaderParameters
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position; // vertex position input
    float2 TextureUV : TEXCOORD0; // first texture coordinate input
};

// Vertex Shader
ShaderParameters VS(ShaderParameters input)
{
    ShaderParameters output = (ShaderParameters) 0;

    output.Position = input.Position;
    output.TextureUV = input.TextureUV;

    return output; // Returns the position without any change to it.
}

// Pixel Shader
float4 PS(ShaderParameters input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 rgbaColor = Texture.Sample(TextureSampler, input.TextureUV);
    float gray = (rgbaColor.r + rgbaColor.g + rgbaColor.b) / 3;
    
    return float4(gray, gray, gray, rgbaColor.a);
}

technique10 GrayscaleTechnique
{
    pass P0
    {
        SetGeometryShader(0);
        SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_5_0, VS()));
        SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_5_0, PS()));
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you clear your depth buffer between passes, so the depth information from the previous pass doesn't prevent future pixels from drawing there?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No I didn't clear the depth buffer between passes. I just gave it a try by doing `deviceContext.ClearDepthStencilView(_depthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1f, 0);`. I placed this list the `deviceContext.Draw(verticeCount, 0)`. Now I'm seeing the opposite issue. The second effect is applied to the output texture but not the first one. I'd assume the first one got overwrote by the second one. I'm not sure to understand why.

Comment: Are you taking the output colour buffer from your first pass and providing it as the input texture for your second pass, rendering to a fresh output colour buffer? If not, can you explain in more detail how you're passing information between these stages?

Comment: I don't think I explicitly pass the texture again. I'm very beginner at it so it's very possible I'm missing a concept here. I update my original post with some code.

Comment: Your shaders can only act on what they're given as input. If you want the second pass to modify the output of the first pass, it needs to receive the first pass's output as input. If the input you give it is the original texture, the output you'll get is the result of applying only that one effect to the original texture.

Comment: Ah yes! That makes absolutely sense then! Thank you very much! Can you please give me some hints at how to do that? Right now I'm passing my ShaderResourceView as a parameter to each shader. But that's the original texture (I think?). Should I create a new ShaderResourceView with the depthStencil texture?

Comment: @DMGregory, thanks again for your suggestion. I tried several things: copying the `_depthStencilTexture` into a new texture and create a new ShadeResourceView with it to pass it to the next Shader effect I'd use, but that doesn't work. Interestingly, using a copy of the output texture I bind to the RenderTargetView doesn't work either.

I also looked at the following post that seem to tries to do the same thing than you suggested by it hasn't been helpful either. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/65850/how-to-print-depth-to-a-texture2d-and-then-read-it-in-the-next-pass-on-a-shader

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more clarity at the steps I should do to reach that goal?

Comment: No, I cannot. But other users can. Your question already asks for help from everyone on the site, so you never need to repeat your question in a comment directed at one user in particular.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. I'll keep digging it while this time and update if I find anything.

Comment: Hi all, I unfortunately still don't succeed to make it work. I tried many things to get the output texture from the first shader to be used as input by the second shader, but I keep seeing the first shader being applied and not the second. As part of all the things I tried, the most relevant is probably create a ShaderResourceView from the OutputTexture from the RenderTargetView when I apply the second effect. While it's probably not optimal, I'd like at least to make it work once before going into optimization. Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Alright I may have figured out WHY it happens. It appears that my output texture is 100% transparent. I was not realizing it because my program send that output texture to a video encoder, which probably doesn't care about transparency (that's what I would assume, but I'd need to verify). So because my output texture is transparent, that would explain why the second effect doesn't render => I give the second shader effect a completely transparent image.

Comment: I think I fixed a part of my issue. I updated my BlendState and now the output texture (after applying the first shader) is "good". It's not completely transparent anymore. Now I'm sending this "good" output texture to the next shader effect.... but it's still not applied. The output texture didn't change. I don't why yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue!

There were 3 problems to my initial code.

1. The first effect I was applying was adding transparency to the image. My BlendState was configured in a way that the output texture would be completely transparent. Therefore, using a completely transparent texture for the next effect would just return something transparent too. I fixed the issue by making a blend state specific to each effect to apply.
2. I wasn't clearing the DepthStencilView and RenderTargetView between each effect. I thought I had to do it between each frame, not each effect.
3. As @DMGregory mentioned (and thanks to you :) ), I needed to make sure to reuse the output texture of the first shader as input for the next one.